# CakePHP / Croogo Plugin Issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am running into a strange issue with Croogo and CakePHP 1.3. I have a plugin called "Ride". 
Within that I have models: Ride, Quote, Service, and Location. All 
have their own controllers, which extend RideAppController which 
extends AppController, as do models extend RideAppModel/ 
AppModel...etc. For some reason, Ride and Quote both show great in 
both front-end and admin (admin_index and index). I am adding all acos in 
activation as well.

However Service and Location do **not** work at all and only show me a 
generic "The requested address was not found on this server." 
error...I don't understand why Ride and Quote work but the other two 
do not?! Really nothing in the models or controllers going on. Any 
thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by renaming the models and controllers to other names and updating rides_activation.php. Not sure if these names are reserved or not.